# Database Refreshing Using FS and Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

So I have this code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Discord.Client();
let db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./database.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

const dawaeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0xD4AF37)
    .setTitle(message.author.username + " fait tourner la roue de la fortune \:\o")
    .setImage('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/HsKDQ0E_aFmmt_y1C0MGjAtkkHEtJqvSgVVC6BEpcBI/https/cdn.zerotwo.dev/INTERNAL/WOF.gif')
    .setFooter('J\'adore les commandes de Ikari :D');


    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (983 - 42 + 1)) + 42;


const dawaeEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0xD4AF37)
    .setTitle(message.author.username + ` a gagné ${result} 〷 grâce à la roue ! ✨`)
    .setImage('https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/0MadJ_5x3-sYSU-8p88EDiks0ieAendhBg5sMSh_RCI/https/cdn.zerotwo.dev/INTERNAL/MONEY.gif')
    .setFooter('J\'adore les commandes de Ikari :D');

    spining = await message.channel.send(dawaeEmbed)
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Edit msg 20 seconds later
        spining.edit(dawaeEmbed2);
      }, 5000);

      if (!db[message.author.id]) db[message.author.id] = {
        money: 0
      };

      let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
      userInfo.money = userInfo.money + result

      fs.writeFile("./database.json", JSON.stringify(db), (x) => {
        if (x) console.error(x)
      });

message.delete();

}
```

But there is a problem... Database is not refreshing after the wheel finished spining. So if i do my command to check the money I have, i still have the money i had before i started the bot. I want to know how to refresh the money ! Help me as fast as you can please...

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this :

```
let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
  userInfo.money = userInfo.money + result
```

By this :

```
db[message.author.id].money = db[message.author.id].money + result
```

And now it works.